How to loop (Rerun code every 60 seconds)
I have a specific code in my app that checks the connection etc. I want this code to be executed every 60 seconds(1 Minute). I don't quite understand the postDelayed() function. Can someone help me please? the code is below.
if (App.connection_status == 2) {
        ConnectionTimer.cancel();
        SharedPreferences SharedAppDetails = getSharedPreferences("settings_data", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor Editor = SharedAppDetails.edit();
        Editor.putString("connection_time", String.valueOf(App.CountDown));
        Editor.apply();

   if (App.CountDown >= 20) {
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings_data", 0);
   String Rate = settings.getString("rate", "false");
if (Rate.equals("false")) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

 @Override
     public void run() {
        Intent Servers = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReviewActivity.class);
                       startActivity(Servers);
                       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right, R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
                       }
                         }, 1000);
                            }
                              }

                       startAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.id.tv_main_count_down, R.anim.fade_out_1000, false);
                       startAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.id.iv_progress_bar, R.anim.fade_out_1000, false);
                       startAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.id.la_animation, R.anim.fade_out_1000, false);
     }


You can extend the class that has this connection checking method with the TimerTask class. Then Override the run method and add the method it should repeatedly run. Finally, in your main method, create a Timer and tell it you want it to run this task every x seconds.
public class JobToDo extends TimerTask {
    public void checkConnection(){
        System.out.println("Checking connection...");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        checkConnection();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new JobToDo(), 0, 1000);
    }
}


The postDelayed() function is part of the Handler class, and it allows you to run a block of code after a specified delay. It's essentially a way to schedule a task to be executed later, after a certain amount of time has passed.
Your current code are using postDelayed() to delay the start of an Intent that opens the Review Activity by 1 second (1000 milliseconds).
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    if (App.connection_status == 2) {
        ConnectionTimer.cancel();
        SharedPreferences SharedAppDetails = getSharedPreferences("settings_data", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor Editor = SharedAppDetails.edit();
        Editor.putString("connection_time", String.valueOf(App.CountDown));
        Editor.apply();

        if (App.CountDown >= 20) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings_data", 0);
            String Rate = settings.getString("rate", "false");
            if (Rate.equals("false")) {
                Handler handler2 = new Handler();
                handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent Servers = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReviewActivity.class);
                        startActivity(Servers);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right, R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
                    }
                }, 1000); // Delay of 1 second before starting ReviewActivity
            }
        }

        startAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.id.tv_main_count_down, R.anim.fade_out_1000, false);
        startAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.id.iv_progress_bar, R.anim.fade_out_1000, false);
        startAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.id.la_animation, R.anim.fade_out_1000, false);
    }

    // Schedule this task to run again in 60 seconds (60000 milliseconds)
    handler.postDelayed(this, 60000); // 60000ms = 1 minute
}
};

// Start the first execution after 0 milliseconds (immediately)
handler.postDelayed(task, 0);

